# Bootstrap height increases on showing error

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I've a bootstrap modal with 3 fields First Name, Second Name, Email. I'm validating the form using laravel 5.2. It is successfully giving back the error messages and I'm printing the same within the div I've created just below the input field. But the issue is error messages are increasing the height of the entire popup.

I would like to show the error message just below the input without increasing the height of the popup. Is there some how I can do that??

```
<div id="registerModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 10%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 register-heading">
                  <center> REGISTER </center>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" action="/user-register" id="register-form">
                  <div id="status-message"></div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Full Name">
                      <span id="first-name-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="second_name" name="second_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                      <span id="second-name-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="register_email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                      <span id="email-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                      <input name="register-submit" type="submit" id="register-form-submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left btn-lg register-button" value="CONTINUE" />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

----Js----

```
if (data.first_name) {
    $("span#first-name-register-error-message").html(data.first_name).show();
}
else {
   $("span#first-name-register-error-message").hide();
}
```

css ------

```
.regsiter-form-fields {
    padding-bottom: 9%; 
}
.error-message-register {
    border-bottom: 1px red solid;
    /** border-radius: 4px; **/
}
```

Comment: Instead of hiding your error messages, you could change the visibility to hidden. This would create your modal at a height that already considers the height of error messages and wouldn't increase/decrease based on your messages being displayed. However, you would have noticeable white space when the errors aren't visible.

Comment: @Tricky12 Nice Solution... But the popup will be big.. Like very big... I want it small and nice...

Answer (score 0):

Please use `position: absolute;` for your error messages and apply some bottom indent on parent to avoid overlapping with other elements...

```
.regsiter-form-fields {
    padding-bottom: 20px; // modify this as per your needs..
}
.register-error-message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've included my css in the question. Tried your solution, nowthe error message is on the top of all the form fields now...

Comment: it will be cool if you will provide a fiddle.. but from your comment what i understand is that bcz of position absolute, error message are taken out from normal flow of DOM.. please increase padding-bottom to 25 or 30px or more if needed so that they do not overlap inputs

Comment: Further, you can reduce font-size of error messages and change bottom position of error messages (may be some -ve bottome indents will be helpful ) to avoid the white space issue between inputs..

Answer (score 0):

As said, you should use absolute positioning to prevent the flow of the document from being interrupted.

However, don't forget to set `position: relative` to each form group, so that the errors show up below the inputs and not stacked on top of each other.

```
.register-form-fields {
  position: relative;
  // padding as required
}

.register-error-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```